# Not able to properly align the code within code block

Tags: discussion, support

I tried to put the code inside the code block in this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105210/how-to-use-page-object-to-put-code-inside-existing-wrapper-and-altering-module), but I failed and not able to do that, meaning it not rendering properly. Is that because of that code or what ?

Comment: Nah, you just need 8 spaces rather than 4 as the code is in a list

Comment: @Clive thanks, post it as an answer!

Comment: Just on mobile so will do later, or feel free to put the answer in yourself it's all good :)

Comment: Clive I'm surprised you are doing editing through mobile itself, that's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As clive pointed out, It just need 8 spaces rather than 4 spaces as the code to render properly.